# Jackson kept using base class to de-serialize object in Java generic base class

Tags: java, generics, jackson

### Title

Jackson failed to deserialize object in Java generic base class.

### Problem Description

I'd like to de-serialize a JSON into an object in Java generic base class, but got exception:

```
ClassCastException: class BaseResult cannot be cast to class MyResult (BaseResult and MyResult are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

The exception is from below:

```java
public abstract class BaseAction<IT extends BaseInput, RT extends BaseResult> {
    public RT execute(final IT inObj) throws Exception {
        //...
        TypeReference<RT> typeRef = new TypeReference<RT>() {};
        return JacksonFunctions.jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(jsonString, typeRef);  //ClassCastException!!
    }
```

Below are the class definitions.

**BaseInput.java**

```java
public abstract class BaseInput {
}
```

**BaseResult.java**

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BaseResult {
    @JsonProperty("ErrorCode")
    private int errorCode = 0;

    @JsonProperty("ErrorMessage")
    private String errorMessage = "";
}
```

**BaseAction.java**

```java
public abstract class BaseAction<IT extends BaseInput, RT extends BaseResult> {

    public RT execute(final IT inObj) throws Exception {
        //...

        TypeReference<RT> typeRef = new TypeReference<RT>() {};
        return JacksonFunctions.jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(jsonString, typeRef);  //ClassCastException!!
    }
}
```

The concreate classes are:

**MyInput.java**

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyInput extends BaseInput {
    private String title;
}
```

**MyResult.java**

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyResult extends BaseResult {
    @JsonProperty("Title")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("Description")
    private String description;
}
```

**MyAction.java**

```java
public class MyAction extends BaseAction<MyInput, MyResult> {
}
```

The program is run like this:

```java
MyInput inObj = new MyInput();
inObj.setTitle("Galaxy");

MyAction act = new MyAction();
MyResult resObj = act.execute(inObj); //exception here!
```

My question is, MyResult (as RT) is passed to the generic base class MyAction, it should be OK to use in BaseAction class (MyResult as RT). But why Jackson is not able to take RT as MyResult to de-serialize JSON string, but as BaseResult (hence the ClassCastException) ?!

Jackson is working fine as below, if I create TypeReference using MyResult class:

```java
TypeReference<MyResult> typeRef = new TypeReference<MyResult>() {};
return JacksonFunctions.jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(jsonString, typeRef);
```

As a workaround, I can take above code to MyAction, it will work fine.

But since the BaseAction already has RT (as MyResult), I don't know why it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that this is due to the type erasure that happens at compile time. This line in `BaseAction` class `TypeReference<RT> typeRef = new TypeReference<RT>() {}` will have a "memory" of only "child class of `BaseResult`" and not **which** particular child class. Since each child may have a different structure, you cannot safely cast the parent to it.

Hence, you can either:

- Provide a `Deserializer` to `BaseResult`, which will have handling for the different implementations, OR
- Provide an abstract method in `BaseResult` to get the implemented type. This can be passed to `readValue(..)` instead of `TypeReference<..>`, as shown below (not compiled or tested, only for indication of the idea):

```java
public abstract class BaseAction<IT extends BaseInput, RT extends BaseResult> {
    /* Method to the get the actual type */
    protected Class<RT> getImplClass();

    public RT execute(final IT inObj) throws Exception {
        //...
        return JacksonFunctions.jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(jsonString, getImplClass());
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyAction extends BaseAction<MyInput, MyResult> {
    protected Class<MyResult> getImplClass(){
        return MyResult.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be extra clear: `new TypeReference<T>() {}` will *never* work. You have to pass a concrete type, not a type variable, to the constructor *directly*. I was hoping the [javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) explained that, but... it doesn't.

Comment: I tried to print some information. The output is:

```java
inObj.getClass().getName() = MyInput
inObj.getClass().getGenericSuperclass().getTypeName() = BaseInput

typeRef.getType() = RT
typeRef.getType().getClass().getName() = sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl
typeRef.getType().getClass().getGenericSuperclass().getTypeName() = sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.LazyReflectiveObjectGenerator
```
The "RT" should be MyResult in my expectation, but it shows "RT" (not even BaseResult?).

Comment: By the way, this example works perfectly as expected in C#.
```C# RT? resObj = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RT>(resJson, options); ```.